# How do I start this objective C animation?

Tags: objective-c

Just started to learn to program for iOS, have a very simple question but can't figure it out.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"robot.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

/* Write your code below this line */

NSArray *robotImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Robot1.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Robot2.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Robot3.png"],
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"Robot4.png"], nil];
imageView.animationImages = robotImages;
imageView.animationDuration = 5.0;
```

Comment: @APerson241 How to I Instruct the 'imageView' to start running the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really now `[imageView startAnimating];`